# Differentiating users from the common router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, web

I'm trying to implement feature "views" for a web application (Like "views" of a video from YouTube). My implementation is it just look to the public IP address for each request and store it. But what if several users use the same WiFi router then they all share the public IP and then like for 10 users I would get just 1 view. Does someone has an experience with that kind of stuff? What I should do in my case? What are my options?

Comment: You'd be better off asking this question on Stack Overflow, where you should be asking programming questions. The short of it is you can't differentiate users by IP. You'll need to implement sessions in your web application, most likely with cookies.

Comment: Solution which with I went to is to increment views counter for each GET request.